# Stream -> findFirst vs findAny

Tags: java-8

A classe [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) possui dois métodos muito semelhantes, `findFirst`e `findAny`. Ambos retornam um `Optional<T>` com um item (ou `empty`caso a `Stream` esteja vazia).

O `findFirst` retorna o primeiro item encontrado. Na prática parece que o `findAny` também está retornando o primeiro item da `Stream`:

```
IntStream.range(1, 10).filter(n -> n % 2 == 0).findFirst().getAsInt(); // 2
IntStream.range(1, 10).filter(n -> n % 2 == 0).findAny().getAsInt();  // 2
```

Nesse sentido não entendi direito o que exatamente o método `findAny` deveria fazer:

- `findAny` é apenas uma implementação "flexibilizada" do `findFirst` que permite melhor performance para streams paralelas (relaxando o requisito de voltar o primeiro item)?
- Quando devo usar cada um dos métodos?

Comment: Não tenho uma resposta, mas acho que essa sua primeira afirmação está correta. Se as streams são simples, ambos retornam o primeiro elemento e pronto. Mas se forem paralelas, não necessariamente, inclusive a documentação diz que duas chamadas iguais a `findAny` podem retornar resultados diferentes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> findAny é apenas uma implementação "flexibilizada" do findFirst que
>   permite melhor performance para streams paralelas (relaxando o
>   requisito de voltar o primeiro item)?

Correcto. O método `findAny` oferece melhor desempenho para parralelismo.

**Documentação of [`findAny`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) :**

> The behavior of this operation is explicitly **nondeterministic**; it is
>   free to select any element in the stream. **This is to allow for maximal
>   performance in parallel operations;** the cost is that multiple
>   invocations on the same source may not return the same result.

É um dos poucos métodos onde o resultado pode mudar usando paralelismo como mencionado na documentação do pacote `java.util.stream` :

> Except for operations identified as explicitly nondeterministic, **such
>   as findAny()**, whether a stream executes sequentially or in parallel
>   should not change the result of the computation.

Em termos de sua outra pergunta,

> Quando devo usar cada um dos métodos?

A principal razão é também especificado na documentação de [`findAny`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) :

> [...]  **(If a stable result is desired, use findFirst() instead.)**